# OSError: [WinError 126] Cannot find the specified module

Tags: pycharm, importerror, mxnet

When I import mxnet package in PyChram,

I met an OSError which I've never met before,

and I don't know how to solve it.

Here's the error information:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "D:/PycharmProjects/LinearRegression/demo/pikachu_detection.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mxnet import image
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mxnet\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from . import engine
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mxnet\engine.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .base import _LIB, check_call
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mxnet\base.py", line 113, in <module>
    _LIB = _load_lib()
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mxnet\base.py", line 105, in _load_lib
    lib = ctypes.CDLL(lib_path[0], ctypes.RTLD_LOCAL)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
```

Wait for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are missing one or more dependency dlls on your system. Try downloading and installing [Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio](https://www.itechtics.com/microsoft-visual-c-redistributable-versions-direct-download-links/#Microsoft_Visual_C_Redistributable_2017). If it did not work check the solutions in [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/1740).

Comment: You are welcome, If you are satisfied with the answer please consider accepting it.